# Celery appropriate for this task?

Tags: python, celery, distributed-computing

This query is related to my [Google Summer of Code project](http://www.google-melange.com/gsoc/project/google/gsoc2012/amitsaha/24001). Basically, I have a master node which delegates build tasks to a number of specified image building nodes. Right now, I do it using a manual, 'scp', folllowed by remote execution using 'ssh' strategy. So, I do not have any scheduling or task distribution - automagically.

I am now looking to use a solution which might be better than my current strategy. I was looking at 'celery' and have played aroud with it just a bit. I have been able to run a simple job remotely. However, from what I understand so far, celery needs the source files at the *worker nodes*. I have also not been able to explore whether celery would do a automatic task distribution/scheduling? I am using RabbitMQ as the broker.

I am new to this, so anyone more experienced would be definitely be able to suggest whether celery is a good choice or is there anything better suitable for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was a little confused. And I have it figured out. Celery will automatically choose one of the workers using the same broker. So, yes, it does the scheduling and distribution.

Comment: Well -- it's the underlying message queue that does the distribution, and _how_ it does that depends on what kind of queue(s) you choose to configure (and what kind of exchange you attach it or them to). If you configure a fanout exchange, generate four workers, attaching two of them to each of two queues on the exchange, then each job would get two workers executing it, one from each queue on the exchange. AMQP is a very flexible architecture, and Celery doesn't stop you from being able to leverage it.

Answer (score 0):

Celery does need access to the worker source, as really it's just a decorator around your functions that cause them to run differently. However, you can change what a worker node is. You just write a python script on the master node that does exactly what you have been doing (scp, ssh). This becomes the "worker". You'd then make a controlling script (feed file locations, urls, so on so forth) also on the master node and run that using Celery. The Celery server would then handle task scheduling, distribution, either via crontab like periodic taks [(here)](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) or you can just wait on the result of a running task ([here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html)) and then have it schedule a new one on finish.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a python script that will connect to the remote celery worker with ssh.
This script assumes you have the necessary permissions and configurations on the remote host.

```
import paramiko

def start_remote_celery_worker(remote_server_ip, remote_username, remote_password, django_project_name):
    # SSH Client
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    try:
        # Connect to the remote server
        ssh.connect(remote_server_ip, username=remote_username, password=remote_password)

        # Command to start the Celery worker
        celery_command = f"celery -A {django_project_name} worker -l info"

        # Execute the Celery worker command on the remote server
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(celery_command)

        # Print the output of the command (optional)
        print(stdout.read().decode('utf-8'))

    except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
        print("Authentication failed. Please check your credentials.")
    except paramiko.SSHException as e:
        print(f"SSH error: {e}")
    finally:
        ssh.close()

# Configuration - Replace with your own values
remote_server_ip = 'your_remote_server_ip'  # Replace with the IP address or hostname of the remote server
remote_username = 'your_remote_username'    # Replace with your remote server username
remote_password = 'your_remote_password'    # Replace with your remote server password (or use key-based authentication)
django_project_name = 'your_project_name'   # Replace with your Django project name

# Call the function to start the Celery worker on the remote server
start_remote_celery_worker(remote_server_ip, remote_username, remote_password, django_project_name)
```